# Fulfillment data dialogflow v2

Tags: dialogflow-es

How is fulfillment data field returned or replaced in dialogflow version 2?
When I receive the fullfillment this field is not informed, and in the documentacion https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-comparison is not mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now `payload`.
Have a look at: https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#response

```
"data": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "this is a simple response"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "facebook": {
      "text": "Hello, Facebook!"
    },
    "slack": {
      "text": "This is a text response for Slack."
    }
}
```

Is now:

```
"payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "this is a simple response"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "facebook": {
      "text": "Hello, Facebook!"
    },
    "slack": {
      "text": "This is a text response for Slack."
    }
  }
```